# How to create custom validation with multiple property dependencies

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, validation, data-annotations

I am struggling with validation of certain values and I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Consider the class below (it's been simplified, leaving out unneeded columns for the solution to the question):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Data_Header
{
    public Data_Header()
    {
        this.Data_Lines = new HashSet<Data_Lines>();
    }

    public int DataHeaderID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CmpWwn { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CntId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DeliveryMethod_SysDeliveryMethodsID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Sys_DeliveryMethods Sys_DeliveryMethods { get; set; }
    public virtual vw_cicmpy vw_cicmpy { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Data_Lines> Data_Lines { get; set; }
}
```

What I have done to create validation for CmpWwn and CntId is create a custom attribute named RequiredGuidAttribute, which I found on StackOverflow somewhere:

```
public class RequiredGuidAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var guid = CastToGuidOrDefault(value);

        return !Equals(guid, default(Guid));
    }

    private static Guid CastToGuidOrDefault(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            return (Guid)value;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e is InvalidCastException || e is NullReferenceException) return default(Guid);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I can use this annotation to validate the Guid value. This was not very difficult and I understand the principle. Now the next issue:

**I would like to make sure the value of DueDate is never before the current date and never before the value of the DeliveryDate property and even more, the value of DueDate should be a calculated value based on the DeliveryMethod**

I'm at a loss; how do I create a validation like this? I am aware that I could simply use a method that returns true or false with a few if statements, but I'd like to use a data annotation if possible so that I can use the same error handler.

I am using database-first with entity framework 6.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to override the IsValid with ValidationContext for become access to your underlying object. Then go for DueDate as for your Guid:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var dataHeader = validationContext.ObjectInstance as Data_Header;
    var dueDate = dataHeader.CalculateDueDate;
    bool isValid = false;

    if (dueDate.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0 ||
        dueDate.CompareTo(dataHeader.DeliveryDate) < 0)
    {
       isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Something like this should do it. You handle this the same way as on Guid before. If you call your Validation you give in the ValidationContext:

For example:

```
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(YOUR_OBJECT_TO_VALIDATE, null, null), results, true);
```